# Is this snippet creating an anonymous Perl hash?

Tags: perl, hash

While reading the snippets provided by [FormFiller](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-FormFiller-0.10/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FormFiller.pm) ( where I kinda got by accident ) , I noticed this line:

```
$f->add_filler( password => Interactive => []);
```

Is this `password => Interactive => []` equivalent to `{"password" => {"Interactive"=>[]}}`? If not, what does it become?

Comment: The `=>` is called a "fat comma" and it is the same as a `,` in your example.  It's not a constructor of any sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Data::Dumper` module is great for answering questions like this. Use the following mock:

```
package Foo;
use Data::Dumper;
sub new { bless {} => shift }
sub add_filler {
  my $self = shift;
  print Dumper \@_;
}
```

Then call it

```
package main;
my $f = Foo->new;
$f->add_filler( password => Interactive => []);
```

and see when you get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'password',
          'Interactive',
          []
        ];
```

This shows that `add_filler` receives a flat list of three arguments: two strings and a reference to an anonymous array.

Answer (score 7):

`=>` is semantically (almost) identical to `,` (see "Comma operator" at [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)), so you're doing this:

```
$f->add_filler( 'password', 'Interactive', [] );
```

<strike>If this calling style is supported by the method</strike> (which it doesn't)<strike>, then it itself would have to convert these arguments into</strike>

```
{ password => { Interactive => [] } }
```

However more typically, hash-style arguments would be passed as a legal hash to begin with:

```
$f->add_filler( password => { Interactive => 1 } );
```

This would be received by the function like this:

```
sub add_filler
{
    my $this = shift;
    my %configs = @_;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you only send a method `password => "Interactive"`, then the method would see that as a single argument, in the form of a hashref, right?

Comment: No, that's still sending two arguments. The method can choose to interpret those arguments as a hash by reading the argument list into a hash rather than an array: `my $this = shift; my %config = @_;`

Comment: You should probably remove everything after that first code block in your answer, because it's only confusing the issue. The `add_filler` function *doesn't* do any hash magic. More specifically, it does this: `my ($self,$name,$class,@args) = @_;` (see here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-FormFiller-0.10/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FormFiller.pm). So it only uses the `=>` operator for its automatic string-interpreting properties.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's exactly the same as

```
$f->add_filler( "password", "Interactive", []);
```